# Can't install newer version nodejs on Debian 8 i386(32bit)

Tags: node.js, npm, 32-bit, i386, debian-jessie

on my debian 8 i386(32bit) server installed nodejs 0.10.15, its worked correctly, but i needed update it to 10.x version. I use some paths to do this, like this:

1. curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - apt-get
   install -y nodejs
2. nvm

### NVM

by nvm i have this error NVM is not compatible with the npm config "prefix"

debug:

```
nvm --version: v0.34.0
$SHELL: /bin/bash
$SHLVL: 1
$HOME: /root
$NVM_DIR: '$HOME/.nvm'
$PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$PREFIX: ''
$NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX: ''
$NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR: ''
$NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR: ''
shell version: 'GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (i586-pc-linux-gnu)'
uname -a: 'Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2 (2017-04-30) i686 GNU/Linux'
OS version: Debian GNU/Linux 8
curl: /usr/bin/curl, curl 7.38.0 (i586-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
wget: /usr/bin/wget, GNU Wget 1.16 built on linux-gnu.
git: not found
grep: /bin/grep, grep (GNU grep) 2.20
awk: not an option: --version
awk: /usr/bin/awk,
sed: /bin/sed, sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
cut: /usr/bin/cut, cut (GNU coreutils) 8.23
basename: /usr/bin/basename, basename (GNU coreutils) 8.23
rm: /bin/rm, rm (GNU coreutils) 8.23
mkdir: /bin/mkdir, mkdir (GNU coreutils) 8.23
xargs: /usr/bin/xargs, xargs (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
nvm current: none
which node:
which iojs:
which npm:
npm config get prefix: -bash: npm: command not found
npm root -g: -bash: npm: command not found
```

i use nvm use --delete-prefix v10.15.0 but have Illegal instruction

### using by curl

after installing nodejs 10.x i check version node --version and npm --version and i have this Illegal instruction, but if i install nodejs 4.x or 5.x and then check version node --version it works correctly, but npm version check give me that Illegal instruction. how i can fix it?

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't install binaries for different CPUs. Every generation of x86 came with a new (larger) instruction set, that's why programs for newer CPUs don't run on older CPUs).

Answer (score 1):

This page says i386 is not supported in 10 and above....

[Here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md)

Available architectures:

NodeSource will continue to maintain the following architectures and may add additional ones in the future.

```
i386 (32-bit)—not available for Node.js 10 and later
amd64 (64-bit)
armhf (ARM 32-bit hard-float, ARMv7 and up: arm-linux-gnueabihf)
arm64 (ARM 64-bit, ARMv8 and up: aarch64-linux-gnu)
```